# Retrieving a record from database getting error as "Invalid column Name" in SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to search a employee name in my database using the below code. But I got an error like **"Invalid column Name"**. But I can find an integer field using same coding.

*Source Code:*

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=True";
    cnn.Open();

    string sqlStr = "select * from emp where Name="+txtName.Text+"";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr,cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        msgLbl.Text = "Record found!";
    }
    else
    {
        msgLbl.Text = "Record not found!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very, VERY susceptible to SQL Injection.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid following in posts: sample code with SQL injection, sample code with missing `using` statements/not closed files/DB connections, "thank you notes" and tags in title.

Comment: in your emp table you have a column name as Name?

Comment: Can you provide table structure

Comment: Its 2013, how are people still writing SQL like this...

Comment: This reminds me of the .NET 1.0 days where everything was put into the click handler method and you ended up with several hundred lines of stuff in each click handler.

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering. I'll try change this code as you recommend. And in my database I have a column name as "Name." As I feel, I can't only search string fields here. But if it were integer, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would assemble sqlStr as:

    `string sqlStr = "select * from emp where Name='"+txtName.Text+"'";`

Note single quotes around the search term.

However, the SQL injection comments imply that your expression should be:

    `string sqlStr = "select * from emp where Name=@StudentName";`

Followed by:

    `da.Parameters.add(new SQLParameter("@StudentName", (object)txtName.text));`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Dbconnection db = new Dbconnection();

            DataTable dt = db.getTable("Select * from view_Cust where CustomerNo=" + txtCustomerNo.Text + "");

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Cust_Id = (int)dt.Rows[0]["Cust_ID"];
                txtCustomerName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();

                DataTable dt1 = db.getTable("Select * from view_CustomerBalance where CustomerNo=" + txtCustomerNo.Text + "");

                if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    txtCustomerBalance.Text = dt1.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    btnsave.Text = "Update";

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record Not Found...");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);

        }


    }
```